# masking a mxn array using python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, scipy

Hii i have a mxn  array data and i want to mask it using 0 and 1 values.Where the values other than 0 is present i want to make it 1 and in place of 0 i want to leave it as it is.If my values are something like this `0.0000609409412` i.e. after decimal point if 4 digits or more are zero then it should be zero not 1

```
Input:
-2.21520694000000e-15   -1.18292704000000e-15   5.42940708000000e-15      
-2.40108895000000e-15    3.09784301000000e-15  -1.18292704000000e-14
 0                       0                      0
 1.50000000000000        2.100000000000000000   1.40000000000000000

output:
1                       1                   1
1                       1                   1
0                       0                   0
1                       1                   1
```

Comment: You can use `np.around` to round to 4 decimal places. and then check for non zero values. Check my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Updated my answer based on your comments.

Try this, simple upper and lower limit-based conditions with an OR `|` operator followed by type conversion to int.

```
lower_limit, upper_limit = -0.00001, 0.00001
masked = ((arr<lower_limit)|(arr>upper_limit)).astype('int')

#Testing it out
[str(j)+'-> masked to -> '+str(masked[i]) for i,j in enumerate(arr)]
```

```
['0.0-> masked to -> 0',
 '1.0-> masked to -> 1',
 '0.1-> masked to -> 1',
 '0.01-> masked to -> 1',
 '0.001-> masked to -> 1',
 '0.0001-> masked to -> 1',
 '1e-05-> masked to -> 0',
 '1e-06-> masked to -> 0',
 '1e-07-> masked to -> 0',
 '1e-08-> masked to -> 0']
```

Comment: will it work for this condition ---if values falls in between -0.0001 and 0.0001 and i want to make it zero then how should i mention threshold

Comment: you mean as an additional condition? or this is your actual condition?

Comment: will 0.001 be zero? or one? Also, will 0 be zero? because it lies between -0.0001 and 0.0001

Comment: additonal condition sir

Comment: it would be 1 sir

Comment: can you answer both the questions in my comment above? what will be the values for 0.001 , 0 and 0.00001 .. can you tell me for all 3 of these numbers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235986/discussion-between-akshay-sehgal-and-anonymos-si).

Answer (score 1):

There are many different ways to achieve this using numpy, e.g. type casting:

```
# given arr is <np.ndarray: m, n> 
new_arr = arr.astype(bool).astype(int)
```

If you want to filter out values below a certain threshold, you can do something like this:

```
threshold = 0.0001
new_arr = (arr >= threshold).astype(int)
```

Comment: ohh sorry i forget to mention one small question. If my values are like this 0.0000609409412 i.e. after decimal if 4 digits or more are zero then it should be zero not 1

Comment: I see, I added how you can filter numbers below a threshold to zero

Comment: if values falls in between -0.0001 and 0.0001 and i want to make it zero then how should i mention threshold

Comment: You can do something like this `new_arr = (np.abs(arr) >= 0.0001).astype(int)` assuming you want all values x < -0.0001 and x > 0.0001 appear as 1 in the new array

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
array = np.array([
    [-2.21520694000000e-15, -1.18292704000000e-15, 5.42940708000000e-15],
    [-2.40108895000000e-15,   3.09784301000000e-15, -1.18292704000000e-14],
    [0                    ,  0                    , 0],
    [1.50000000000000     ,  2.100000000000000000 , 1.40000000000000000]
])
result = (array != 0).astype('int')
```